# Webscraping in node.js

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

I followed a simple tutorial online, which used this code to open and log a webpage:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')

async function getPriceFeed() {
  try{
    const siteUrl = 'coinmarketcap.com'
    const data = await axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: siteUrl,
    })
    console.log(data)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}

getPriceFeed()
```

The code is simple enough, but in my console log I get this:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 80,
  config: {
    url: 'coinmarketcap.com',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.1'
    },
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
```

etc, etc.

What am I looking at? And why doesn't it return a long html string?

Comment: your url looks wrong, did you want to write this ? https://coinmarketcap.com/

Comment: I'll try! Testing... no, it still shows the same thing in the console

Comment: I've tried other methods as well, including puppeteer and fetch, with mixed results. In a few cases I was able to get the html string, but it always followed what I posted in the picture and only worked for a few websites, most websites had the problem I described above.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL is wrong: It should be `https://coinmarketcap.com/` and not `http://www.https://coinmarketcap.com/`.

```
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')

async function getPriceFeed() {
try{
    const siteUrl = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/'
    const data = await axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: siteUrl,
    })
    console.log(data)
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
}
}

getPriceFeed()
```

Comment: That's fair, and I've edited the question to use a url that should work. However, the problem persists. I'm writing the code and running it of repl.it, do you think that's the issue?

Comment: It should work on replit also. There must be another issue. Check this repl https://replit.com/join/dgxgbprfhj-ridhamtarpara

Comment: Thanks! That's so bizarre, perhaps there's an issue with my other dependencies? I'm running this as part of a discord bot, so perhaps there's something with discord.js that's a problem?

Comment: yes, it can be. Looking at the error looks like a network or proxy issue @MachDiscord

Comment: OK, so that worked. Now to see which part of the code is different... Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: So I don't really understand what you did different. Which parts of the code did you edit?

Comment: I'm also having trouble with writing the selector... the following code doesn't return anything:

`$(elemSelector).each((parentIdx, parentElem) => {
        if (parentIdx <= 9){
          console.log(parentIdx)
        }
    })`